# mklink: junction actually doesn't work

Tags: mklink

I did this from `cmd.exe` as admin

```
mklink /J "C:\Users\absolute\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup" "E:\iPhone DATA\iTunes BACKUP”
```

and I see confirmation of Junction in cmd and even do

```
DIR "C:\Users\absolute\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync"
```

and see smth like

```
28.02.2015 10.27 <JUNCTION> Backup ["E:\iPhone DATA\iTunes BACKUP"]
```

so it should work. But when I try to click on Backup link in File Explorer it brings error Location is not available